# DurandalJS app.showMessage modals cause Y-overflow artifact

Tags: css, durandal, durandal-2.0

Durandal has composition support for modal dialogs. I've been able to use them successfully, though there's a strange graphical artifact I cannot seem to eradicate. I'm pretty sure it's part of a div with class 'durandal-wrapper', though it's not present until runtime. How can I prevent this behavior without resorting to monkey patching some "overflow-y:blah;" onto an element after it's created and attached to the DOM by Durandal?

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A durandal view must have a single root element and will create one if it doesn't exist. Try wrapping your views inside a root div tag and it should render without that class name.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/y88-uakWn6k